# Connection between 2 different servers Express.js and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I  have a **Experss.js** framework and **Node.js** with a request to MS SQL database on the server side.

I want to get a data(in JSON or array) from server and send to Cliend side.

I don't understand how can I write routers for another server on the Client side.

server.js

```
npm start
http://localhost:5000/
```

Code:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http')
var query = "SELECT AVG([sta_waittime]) AS Spalte FROM [DialogMaster_TEST].[dwh].[anruf_stat] WHERE CONVERT(DATE,sta_timestamp) = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(DATE,'2016-08-01')) ";

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  sql.connect("mssql://log:pas@db/TEST").then(function() {
    // Query

    new sql.Request().query(query).then(function(recordset) {
        var a = [];
        a.push(recordset[0].Spalte);
        res.send(a);   // **number**
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // ... query error checks
    });


    }).catch(function(err) {
        // ... connect error checks
    });

});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Server site in Browser:

[image: Server site in Browser]

My app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

//app.get('/');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the workflow more and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's quite unclear what  you're asking. You are already making a request to the db and sending data back. What is `app.js` for? It's not being used in your service.

Comment: app.js is like a config file for framework. If I sending data back how can i display it?

Comment: You cannot get data from another server. What you can do is create an endpoint like '/getServerAData' in ServerA that returns the data you need and call that endpoint from ServerB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only 1 server(REST server). Just use node.js server.

Read it:
[REST](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm)